# Why the searchContainer variable is unknown?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to do a simple example with the `searchContainer` working with `liferay 6.1.`

The `searchContainer variable` is unknown in `view.jsp.`
 I get the error `"searchContainer cannot be resolved".`

I tried to include `<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>`

It didn't work.

Code looks like this:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container iteratorURL="<%= actionURL %>" delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-documents">
<liferay-ui:search-container-results total="<%= list.size() %>" results="<%= ListUtil.subList(list, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />
```

#### Update

I am using the varibale **searchContainer** in `search-container-results` tag and in the `search-iterator` tag

```
 <liferay-ui:search-container iteratorURL="<%= actionURL %>"
     delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-documents">
         <liferay-ui:search-container-results total="<%= list.size() %>"
         results="<%= ListUtil.subList(list, searchContainer.getStart(), 
         searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />
         <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="file        
         className="DLFileEntry">
         .
         .
         .
         </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
         <liferay-ui:search-iterator
          searchContainer="<%= searchContainer %>"
          paginate="${fn:length(listFiles) ge 10}" />
 </liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Comment: It looks like [you asked the question in a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813428) as well and solved it there. Not exactly a duplicate, but a pointer that the same underlying problem has been solved by the same person. Feels like you wouldn't expect any more answer on this question?

Comment: what do you mean?  This is a different question. the code works fine but there is an error: **Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - searchContainer cannot be 
  resolved**

Answer (score 0):

In principle your code should work. I'd look for these options, in order of probability:

1. Either you're cl the search-container tag before you use the search-container-results tag, thus searchContainer would be out of scope. (assuming you might have shortened the code here, or you have another reference to searchContainer, not just the one that you're showing here.
2. or you're declaring the variable explicitly to be named differently, e.g. `<liferay-ui:search-container var="myOwnNameForSearchContainer" ...>`, again this assumes that you've severely shortened the sample code here
3. or the tag library is not recognized (low probability).

How to mitigate?

1. Watch out for other references to `searchContainer` later on the page, particularly after the occurrence of `</liferay-ui:search-container>`.
2. should be obvious
3. Shorten the page to just `<liferay-ui:searchContainer ... > </liferay-ui:search-container>` and make sure that this gets replaced with actual HTML code, and this particular markup is no longer existing in the HTML output when you render the page, then add individual other elements.

Comment: I am using the varibale **searchContainer** in `search-container-results` tag and in the `search-iterator` tag. see the update. What should i do?